# Java check all characters in string are present in a given string array

Tags: java, arrays, string, character

I am attempting to create a method that checks every character in userInput to see if they are present in operatorsAndOperands. The issue is that tempbool is always false for all values.

```
import java.util.*;

public class stringCalculator
{
private String userInput = null;
String[] operatorsAndOperands = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","+","-","*","/"};

public stringCalculator(String newInput)
{
    userInput = newInput;
}

public boolean checkInput()
{
    boolean ifExists = true;
    for(int i=0; i<userInput.length(); i++)
    {
        char currentChar = userInput.charAt(i);
        boolean tempbool = Arrays.asList(operatorsAndOperands).contains(currentChar);
        if (tempbool == false)
        {
            ifExists = false;
        }
    }
    return ifExists;
}
}
```

Comment: currentChar's data type is `char`, and your operands' data type are `Strings`. `tempbool` will always be false.

Comment: operatorsAndOperands is a String array, and you're comparing with a char in the loop

Comment: Also note that you can `break;` your loop in the if statement (there's no need to check if others characters are valid or not because you found one that was not).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you have an array of string objects (which you later convert to a list of string objects), but you are checking a `char` for presence in that array.

Efficiency is also pretty poor here - converting a fixed array to a list on each iteration takes a lot of unnecessary CPU cycles.

A simple solution to this problem is to put all characters in a string, and then check each incoming character against that string:

```
if ("0123456789+-*/".indexOf(currentChar) >= 0) {
    ... // Good character
}
```

Another solution would be making a regex that allows only your characters to be specified, like this:

```
if (expr.replaceAll("[0-9+/*-]*", "").length() == 0) {
    ... // Expr contains only valid characters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you declare

```
String[] operatorsAndOperands = {"1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","+","-","*","/"};
```

as a String, instead of an array of String.  Then you can just use the contains method to check the characters against the valid operators.

Answer (score 0):

Declare: `char[] operatorsAndOperands;` instead of: `String[] operatorsAndOperands`.

Or add this: String.valueOf(charToCompare) as the "contains" argument.

Answer (score 0):

As has been pointed out, the issue is that you're checking for a `char` in a list of `String` objects, so you'll never find it.

You can make this check easier, though, by using a regular expression:

```
Pattern operatorsAndOperands = Pattern.compile("[0-9+\\-*/]");
```